# What is the meaning of $this

Tags: php, variables

I've seen some scripts contain `$this` in a PHP script that has OOP, I never knew the meaning of it... like

```
$this->refresh();
```

Perhaps explain to me what `$this` refers to be...?

But I do know that you cannot use it as a dynamic variable like `$this_is_a_variable` but why can't use it as a dynamic variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$this` is a reference to the current object.

It can be used in class methods only.

From [the manual:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

a simple real world example:

```
class Classname
{
  private $message = "The big brown fox... jumped....";

  function setMessage($givenMessage) {
    $this->message = $givenMessage;
  }

  function getMessage() {
    return $this->message;  // Will output whatever value 
                            // the object's message variable was set to
  }
}

$my_object = new Classname();  // this is a valid object
echo $my_object->getMessage();  // Will output "The big brown fox... jumped...."

$my_object->setMessage("Hello World!");
echo $my_object->getMessage();  // Will output "Hello world"
```

`$this` is *not* available when you call a method in a *static* context:

```
Classname::showMessage(); // Will throw an error: 
                          // `$this` used while not in object context
```

Comment: Well, that was a pretty fast answer Pekka :P I'll read the manual, I didn't know where to find about `$this` in the PHP Manual/Documentation. Thanks. :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure showMessage will display "The big brown fox... jumped..." instead of "Hello World!". You probably meant $my_object->message

Comment: the use of 'var' should be replaced by 'private' or even 'protected' for class members. (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: I've updated this answer to use a getter and a setter, which is more common for a basic class :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing OOP then you use classes. You can have:

```
class CFoo
  {
  private $var;
  public function setFoo($fooVal)
    {
    $this->var = $fooVal;
    }
  }
```

$this refers to the current object of that class.

Answer (score 3):

When creating classes within PHP, at times you may need to reference the class* itself. The `$this` variable is reserved for this purpose.

**This should be correct as 'referring to the object created' not the class. This is semantically more correct.*

For example:

```
class Car
{
    private $make;

    public function setMake($make)
    {
         $this->make = $make;
    }

    public function setModel($model)
    {
         $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function whatCar()
    {
        return "This car is a " . $this->make . " " . $this->model;
    }
}
```

And to use it would look something like:

```
$car = new Car();

$car->setMake('Ford');
$car->setModel('Escort');

echo $car->whatCar();
//This car is a Ford Escort
```

Comment: I realize I'm nitpicking here, but `$this` references an *object* of the given class. To refer to the *class* itself, the `__CLASS__` magic constant is used.

Comment: I plus'd one to you for my mistake. I'll leave the error in for reference but you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to the current object of the class. $this is used in methods which are members of a particular class. Hence, inside those methods, the method already has the information about the particular "instance" of that class. So $this can be directly used to refer the current object, rather than retrieving and assigning an object to a different variable.