# What does $this mean in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, this, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: self vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Hello,
Could you help me understanding the meaning of the PHP variable name `$this`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this. Also, please don't be too cute in questions. ;)

Comment: Congratulations on expanding your knowledge at the age of 12! But since that's not relevant to the question, could you edit the question to remove it?

Comment: It appears that people on Stack Overflow do not know what 'I am 12 years old and what is this' refers to.

Comment: How is this a dupe, he is not comparing the usage of `self` versus `$this` is specifically wanted to know **what** `$this` means.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I'm%2012%20years%20old%20and%20what%20is%20this%3F

Answer (score 17):

`$this` refers to the class you are in.

For example

```
Class Car {

    function test() {
        return "Test function called";
    }

    function another_test() {
        echo $this->test(); // This will echo "Test function called";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a way of referencing itself... or calling methods or reading variables from itself.

Comment: actually, self refers to the current class you are in. $this refers to the current object instance of the class you are in.

Comment: It won't `echo "Test functioned called"` since you're accessing the `test` member variable (which doesn't exist) as opposed to the method `test()`.  You'd need to change it to `echo $this->test()`...

Comment: It's not really the *class*, but the *object* - an *instance* of a class.

Comment: Well actually its an instance of that class, where as `self` would refer to the class statically, and `__CLASS__` would refer to the classname as a string :-)

Comment: @jodm, I edited the question and added the needed parentheses, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the answers in [In PHP5, what is the difference between using self and $this? When is each appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Basically, `$this` refers to the current object.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is a protected variable that's used within a object, `$this` allows you to access a class file internally.

Example

```
Class Xela
{
   var age; //Point 1

   public function __construct($age)
   {
      $this->setAge($age); //setAge is called by $this internally so the private method will be run
   }

   private function setAge($age)
   {
      $this->age = $age; //$this->age is the variable set at point 1
   }
}
```

Its basically a variable scope issue, `$this` is only allowed within a object that has been initiated and refers to that object and its parents only, you can run private methods and set private variables where as out side the scope you cannot.

also the `self` keyword is very similar apart from it refers to static methods within *class*, static basically means that you cant use `$this` as its not an object yet, you must use `self::setAge();` and if that `setAge` method is declared static then you cannot call it from an instant of that object / `object`

Some links for you to get started:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
- [How to explain 'this' keyword in a best and simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way)
- [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Comment: While I understand you are explaining to an OOP newcomer, please do not refer to objects as classes.

$this is used to refer to object properties and methods, while self:: is used to refer to class properties and methods.

I think it is important to explain the difference between the two.