# How to invoke a method statically?

Tags: php, oop, methods, method-chaining

```
<?php
class Popular
{
    public static function getVideo()
    {
        return $this->parsing();
    }
}

class Video 
    extends Popular
{
    public static function parsing()
    {
        return 'trololo';
    }

    public static function block()
    {
        return parent::getVideo();
    }
}

echo Video::block();
```

I should definitely call the class this way:

```
Video::block();
```

and not initialize it

```
$video = new Video();
echo $video->block()
```

Not this!

```
Video::block(); // Only this way <<
```

But:
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in myFile.php on line 6

How to call function "parsing" from the "Popular" Class?

Soooooooory for bad english

Comment: on a related note, read about late static bindings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: You should avoid static methods if possible. [They are death to testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability).

Comment: You can not use $this in static context. Use self as suggested below.

Comment: *(related)* [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and) and [What exactly is late-static binding in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-is-late-static-binding-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your using a static method, you cant use `$this`keyword as that can only be used within objects, not classes.

When you use the `new` keyword, your creating and **object** from a class, if you have not used the new Keyword then `$this` would not be available as its not an **Object**

For your code to work, being static you would have to use the `static` keyowrd along with `Scope Resolution Operator (::)` as your method is within a parent class and its its not bounded, Use the `static` keyword to call the parent static method.

Example:

```
class Popular
{
    public static function getVideo()
    {
        return static::parsing(); //Here
    }
}
```

- [What does $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124982/what-does-this-mean-in-php-closed)
- [paamayim-nekudotayim - Scope Resolution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1):

change `return $this->parsing();` to `return self::parsing();`

Comment: `self::parsing()` will try to call `Popular::parsing()`, which doesn't exist. If using PHP 5.3.0 (or later), you should use late static bindings, i.e. `static::parsing()`.