# PHP Method Chaining With Parent

Tags: php, method-chaining

Lets say i have the following code.

```
class A {
    function one() {
        return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function two() {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Is there any way possible that i can method chain using a function from the parent class?
Such as..

```
$b = new B();
$b->one()->two();
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? It works for me Add some echo's in there and you will see the output in the correct order.

Comment: @Gohn67 - Your right,.. so in my real method there must be something else wrong, the page keeps crashing. I guess i should of tested out this simplified version first. :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way) for several responses that explain the meaning of the special variable `$this`.

In short, it refers to the current object.  You're creating an instance of `B`, so even if you refer to `$this` within `function one()` you're still referring to the enclosing instance.

Comment: B inherits from A, so I think his code example actually works.

Comment: Yes, the code does execute.  I didn't say the code doesn't work.  I just said that `$this` is going to refer to the instance of `B` in both cases.